How to hide API requests in Nuxt.js to prevent them from appearing in the Browser console?
I'm developing an application with Nuxt and using useFetch to fetch data from an API. In theory, with SSR rendering, these requests shouldn't appear in the browser’s console, but with Nuxt, I can still see them. How can I prevent this? I don’t want others to see my request information.
I tried using
const { data } = await useFetch('/api/your-endpoint', { server: true })

but it didn’t work. I want to prevent backend requests from being visible in the browser console.

By console, what do you mean? Is it logging in the console and what does it look like? If you mean Network tab, there is no way for you to make that unavailable to users and you will always see network requests there.

Yes, it's a network panel. I think if you're using SSR rendering, the XHR request should not be visible in the browser's network panel.

Server side rendering would still be making network requests. You cannot hide requests from the network tab. It doesn't matter what tool you are using to write the code. That isn't possible.

See https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-island , and https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#server-only-pages , and https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/components#server-components

@LukeBecker if it's SSR, then the logic happens on the Node.js side so presumably it shouldnt occur on the browser network tab?
